# How to display set of labels one after the other in c# wpf window?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I have a wpf window which has four labels m1,m2,m3,m4.When I click a button in the window,all the four labels should be displayed one after the other.But I'm getting all the labels displayed at once which shouldn't happen.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
m1.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "      Establishing Connection";
//some code
m2.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "      Connected";
//some code
m3.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "      Processing";
//some code
m4.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "      Finished";

}
```

After running the application the window shows the following all labels displayed at once not one after the other as per the time

> 10:14:20      Establishing Connection
>
> 10:14:24      Connected
>
> 10:14:26      Processing
>
> 10:14:30      Finished

Answer (score 1):

The container you are looking for is called a StackPanel, it will automatically place any elements inside it one after another.

Example

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Name="m1"/>
            <Label Name="m2"/>
            <Label Name="m3"/>
            <Label Name="m4"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is after setting the `Content` of the `Label` you can toggle the `Visibility` of the `Label` so that instead of getting all the `Label` at once you would get it one by one. As @Dan suggested use a `StackPanel` to arrange the `Label`. Also take care of one important point that the UI thread is updated after each operation.

Below is the sample code used by me.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Testing" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Label Name="m1" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Label Name="m2" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Label Name="m3" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <Label Name="m4" Visibility="Hidden" />
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private async void Button_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m1.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString ("HH:mm:ss") + "      Establishing Connection";
        m1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        await Task.Run (() => Thread.Sleep (2000));
        m2.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString ("HH:mm:ss") + "      Connected";
        m2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        await Task.Run (() => Thread.Sleep (2000));
        m3.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString ("HH:mm:ss") + "      Processing";
        m3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        await Task.Run (() => Thread.Sleep (2000));
        m4.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString ("HH:mm:ss") + "      Finished";
        m4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        await Task.Run (() => Thread.Sleep (2000));
    }
}
```

I hope it helps. You can also use `BackgroundWorker` to avoid UI freezing.

Below is the code using `BackgroundWorker`

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        m1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        m2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        m3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        m4.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            m1.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "      Establishing Connection";
            m1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });
        Thread.Sleep(2000);//your code
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            m2.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "      Connected";
            m2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });
        Thread.Sleep(2000);//your code
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            m3.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "      Processing";
            m3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });
        Thread.Sleep(2000);//your code
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            m4.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "      Finished";
            m4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        });
        Thread.Sleep(2000);//your code
    }
}
```

Comment: How an I use BackgroundWorker to display these labels one after the other?

Comment: @user3559120 I have added an example using `BackgroundWorker` also. Just add a using statement `using System.ComponentModel;` in your class